# Gridstack undefined when calling $(".grid-stack").data("gridstack") in global context

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

Gridstack is a javascript library that can be found [here](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js). I don't know whether I need to define grid within the original function it was created, but I can't seem to call gridstack and get it defined. How do I call gridstack in the context I want to below? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
$("#button").click(function(){

 //var el ='<div class="grid-stack-item-content" />Test<div/>';
 var grid = $(".grid-stack").data("gridstack");
 alert(grid); //This is undefined

 });

  $(function () {
   var options = {
       cell_height: 80,
       vertical_margin: 10
   };

   $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);

  });
```

Comment: let me know if you are still interest in this, i can help you out

Comment: It should be working this way. Please check out this sample http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/serialization.html

Comment: You initialize gridstack on a local scope and your trying to access it globally. It should be within the anonymous function.