# Unable to load layout content from browser storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gridstack

I am using a `library` called **gridstack.js**. I have a `grid` which looks like below ↓

[image]

This is the code I used:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@2.0.0/dist/gridstack.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@2.0.0/dist/gridstack.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>

.card-body {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

.newWidget {
    background-color: #6cad84 !important;
}
.card {
    background: none;
}

#trash {
    background-color: #cc6857;
}
.text-white {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}

    
.ui-resizable-se, .ui-resizable-sw {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
    bottom: -5px !important;
    right: -5px !important;
}


.grid-stack-item-content{
    overflow:hidden !important
}

    

</style>


<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <span id="dashboardName">
        <p>My dashboard</p>
    </span>

    <div class="row">


        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "> 

            <!-- gridstack.js elements go here -->
            <div class="grid-stack">
               

             <div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="3" data-gs-width="7" data-gs-height="4">
                    <div class="grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle card-color card-body cardProperty">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541890289-b86df5bafd81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">

                    </div>
              </div>


              <div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable hasPanelHeader " data-gs-x="8" data-gs-y="6" data-gs-width="5" data-gs-height="4">
              
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle  panel-warning  card-body cardProperty">
                            
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541890289-b86df5bafd81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
                </div>
            </div>

             


              <div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="6" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
                    
                    <div class="grid-stack-item-content card-body ui-draggable-handle card-color cardProperty">
                        
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541890289-b86df5bafd81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">

                    </div>
             </div>


             <div class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable hasPanelHeader " data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="6" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
              
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content ui-draggable-handle  panel-warning  card-body cardProperty">
                            
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541890289-b86df5bafd81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"> 
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

     </div> 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

// save the size and coordinates of the widgets
function saveData() {
    var items = [];

    $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        items.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
        });
    });

    // Save data to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("grid-layout", JSON.stringify(items))
}


// check for widgets size and coordinates and add to the grid
function getWidgetData() {

    let serialization = null;
    let grid_stack = $('.grid-stack');
    let grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack')
    console.log("grid", grid)

    if (localStorage.getItem("grid-layout") !== null) {

        serialization = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("grid-layout"));

        _.each(JSON.parse(serialization), function (node) {
            grid.addWidget($('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content"> </div></div>'),
                node.x, node.y, node.w, node.h);
        });

       
    } else {
        console.log("There was no local storage data to read")
    }
}


// check for localstorage in the beginning
getWidgetData ()

var simpleGrid = GridStack.init({
      alwaysShowResizeHandle: /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator
        .userAgent),
      resizable: {
        handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w, n'
      },
      animate: true,
      acceptWidgets: true,
      dragIn: '.newWidget',  // class that can be dragged from outside
      dragInOptions: { revert: 'invalid', scroll: false, appendTo: 'body', helper: 'clone' },
      removable: '#trash', // drag-out delete class
      removeTimeout: 100,
});

// save the widgets layout on every change
simpleGrid.on('added removed change', function(e, items) {
    saveData()
});

</script>

</body>
```

Now the `grid` appears fine and I am able to `resize` and `drag` the `widgets`. Now I want to `store` the changes in my browser storage and retrieve it on page load. So as mentioned in the code above, this is what I do to `store` the layout

```
// save the size and coordinates of the widgets
function saveData() {
    var items = [];

    $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        items.push({
            x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
            y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
            w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
            h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
            content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
        });
    });

    // Save data to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("grid-layout", JSON.stringify(items))
}
```

Now to `load` the layout from browser storage, this is what I do (mentioned in the code above)

```
// check for widgets size and coordinates and add to the grid
function getWidgetData() {

    let serialization = null;
    let grid_stack = $('.grid-stack');
    let grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack')
    console.log("grid", grid)

    if (localStorage.getItem("grid-layout") !== null) {

        serialization = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("grid-layout"));

        _.each(JSON.parse(serialization), function (node) {
            grid.addWidget($('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content"> </div></div>'),
                node.x, node.y, node.w, node.h);
        });


    } else {
        console.log("There was no local storage data to read")
    }
}
```

But for some reason I get this error

```
index.html:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addWidget' of undefined
    at index.html:156
    at r (lodash.min.js:9)
    at Function.hf (lodash.min.js:83)
    at getWidgetData (index.html:155)
    at index.html:168
```

Turns out this piece of code below

```
 let grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack')
```

It gives **undefined** for some reason. Now I just can't figure out why it is undefined. I looked up online for help but didn't find anything useful that solves my problem. I found these two questions on stack overflow

[Gridstack undefined when calling $(".grid-stack").data("gridstack") in global context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410402/gridstack-undefined-when-calling-grid-stack-datagridstack-in-global-co)

[can't read property addWidget of undefined with JSON and gridstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287633/cant-read-property-addwidget-of-undefined-with-json-and-gridstack)

But I don't quite understand what they are doing or if it applies in my case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the 'bug' reported https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/1405, he's mixing old API call of `$(".grid-stack")` which is jquery code based for v0.6 and older and the latest version 2.x which uses `GridStack.init()` to init and return a grid pointer.

**GridStack does not use jquery API since 1.x**

Comment: oh so I was using older functionalities. Ok now this makes sense. Let me try out the latest functionalities and fix the problem. Thanks!